# 話を聞く connected?

Tags: words

I have this sentence:

> これはアヤメに話を聞く重大なルールだ。

I understand this as:

> this is a serious rule to follow to chat with Ayame. (Correct me if it's inaccurate)

話を聞く look to me like they're connected but i can't find anything about it anywhere.

Context: A person speakers to an interviewer about their boss.  Olivia, Ayame is the boss of the person who says all this to an interviewer who wants to interview her.

Comment: 話を聞く is “to listen to a story.” Does that help?

Comment: Can you add any context to the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think 'chat' is a little inappropriate.

The Japanese phrase ‘話を聞く’ refers to listening to someone's story (sometimes problem), so it is more important than a chat. 
What theme is important depends on one’s subjective thoughts.

For example,

> 「どうしたの？何か嫌なことでもあった？**話聞くよ？**」
>   the situation: A girl looked sad and her friend tried to console her with listening what happened to her.
>
> 「ちょっと**お話**があるのですが」
>   the situation: Since he wanted to discuss the plan he had been in charge of, an office worker asked for his boss’s time.

---

> これはアヤメに話を聞く重大なルールだ。

Since I don’t know the situation I can't explain it perfectly. But my expectation is that when the speaker ask Ayame some information, he or she has to follow the rule, like giving her equivalent information.

I thought of アヤメ**に**話を聞く as asking her something, but I don’t know whether it is proper. If you give me the situation, I think I can tell you more correctly. :)